# Operator Overload with Derived Class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I am at my wits end and after literally 12 hours of getting no where I need some help. I believe I am missing a fundamental key to this problem. I have the following code below, sorry it's a lot, just didn't want to leave anything out.  Let me say that this is indeed HW but when your teacher doesn't email back and nothing on google has helped, I implore all you guys wisdom and knowledge.

**My Problem:** I can't figure out how to overload the operator+ for the linkedBag.h class. I believe my prototype is fine, I just can't figure out how to implement it. I have tried many things such as what I have written but please hold the laughing the a minimum since I know it's wrong, ha. Thanks for any help.

MAIN.CPP

```
** Listing 4-4. */
#include "BagInterface.h"
//#include "ArrayBag.h"
#include "LinkedBag.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
/* no longer used in version 2.1, use << operator 
void displayBag(BagInterface<string>* bagPtr)
{
   cout << "The bag contains " << bagPtr->getCurrentSize()
   << " items:" << endl;
    vector<string> bagItems = bagPtr->toVector();

   int numberOfEntries = (int)bagItems.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
   {
      cout << bagItems[i] << " ";
   }  // end for
   cout << endl;
}  // end displayBag
******/
void bagTester(BagInterface<string>* bagPtr1, BagInterface<string>* bagPtr2)
{

   string items1[] = {"one", "six", "three", "four", "five", "one", "three"};
   string items2[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "three"};
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
   {
      bagPtr1->add(items1[i]);
   }  // end for

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
      bagPtr2->add(items2[i]);
   }  // end forA
   //displayBag(bagPtr1);
   cout << bagPtr1 << endl;
   cout << boolalpha << "contains 'one' for bag1 returns : " 
    << bagPtr1->contains("one")
           << " frequency: " << bagPtr1-> getFrequencyOf("one")
           <<endl<<endl;
   //displayBag(bagPtr2);
   cout << bagPtr2 << endl;
   cout << boolalpha << "contains 'one' for bag1 returns : " 
    << bagPtr2->contains("one")
           << " frequency: " << bagPtr2-> getFrequencyOf("one")
           <<endl<<endl;
}  // end bagTester
int main()
{
   BagInterface<string>* bagPtr1 = nullptr;
   BagInterface<string>* bagPtr2 = nullptr;
   BagInterface<string>* bagPtr3 = nullptr;
   char userChoice;
   cout << "Enter 'A' to test the array-based implementation\n"
   << " or 'L' to test the link-based implementation: ";
   cin >> userChoice;
   if (toupper(userChoice) == 'A')
   {
      //bagPtr1 = new ArrayBag<string>();
      //bagPtr2 = new ArrayBag<string>();
      //bagPtr3 = new ArrayBag<string>();
      //cout << "Testing the Array-Based Bag:" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      bagPtr1 = new LinkedBag<string>();
      bagPtr2 = new LinkedBag<string>();
      bagPtr3 = new LinkedBag<string>();
      cout << "Testing the Link-Based Bag:" << endl;
   }  // end if
   // test both bags have items
   bagTester(bagPtr1, bagPtr2);
   //test Bag version 2.1 new methods
   //(*bagPtr3) = (*bagPtr1) + (*bagPtr2);
   //cout<<bagPtr3<<endl;
   //bagPtr3->bagSort();
   //cout<<bagPtr3;
   bagPtr1 = nullptr;
   bagPtr2 = nullptr;
   bagPtr3 = nullptr;
   cout << "All done!" << endl;

   return 0;
}  // end main*
```

BAGINTERFACE.H

```
/** Listing 1-1.
    @file BagInterface.h */
#ifndef _BAG_INTERFACE
#define _BAG_INTERFACE

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface
{
public:
    //destructor
    virtual ~BagInterface() {}; 
   /** Gets the current number of entries in this bag.
    @return The integer number of entries currently in the bag. */
   virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;

   /** Sees whether this bag is empty.
    @return True if the bag is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Adds a new entry to this bag.
    @post  If successful, newEntry is stored in the bag and
       the count of items in the bag has increased by 1.
    @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry.
    @return  True if addition was successful, or false if not. */
   virtual bool add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;

   /** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this bag,
       if possible.
    @post  If successful, anEntry has been removed from the bag
       and the count of items in the bag has decreased by 1.
    @param anEntry  The entry to be removed.
    @return  True if removal was successful, or false if not. */
   virtual bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;

   /** Removes all entries from this bag.
    @post  Bag contains no items, and the count of items is 0. */
   virtual void clear() = 0;

   /** Counts the number of times a given entry appears in bag.
    @param anEntry  The entry to be counted.
    @return  The number of times anEntry appears in the bag. */
   virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

   /** Tests whether this bag contains a given entry.
    @param anEntry  The entry to locate.
    @return  True if bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise. */
   virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

   /** Empties and then f ills a given vector with all entries that
       are in this bag.
    @return  A vector containing all the entries in the bag. */
   virtual vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;

    /*******************************************************
    Description     :   Will combine contents of both bags including duplicates into a single bag
    Arguments       :   BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag
    Returns         :   BagInterface<ItemType>*
    Precondition    :   A valid BagInterface pointer object
    Postcondition   :   BagInteface pointer object with combined object elements
    *******************************************************/
   virtual BagInterface<ItemType>* combine( BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const = 0;

    /*******************************************************
    Description     :   Will show only items that are different in both bags
    Arguments       :   BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag
    Returns         :   BagInterface<ItemType>*
    Precondition    :   A valid BagInterface pointer object
    Postcondition   :   BagInteface pointer object that points to a bag with only elements
                    :   that are not shared by both bags.
    *******************************************************/
   virtual BagInterface<ItemType>* diff( BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const = 0;

    /*******************************************************
    Description     :   Elements that are shared by both bags are returned, no duplicates
    Arguments       :   BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag
    Returns         :   BagInterface<ItemType>*
    Precondition    :   A valid BagInterface pointer object
    Postcondition   :   BagInteface pointer object with elements that are shared with
                    :   both bags, no duplicates
    *******************************************************/
   virtual BagInterface<ItemType>* intersection( BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const = 0;

   virtual BagInterface<ItemType>& operator+(const BagInterface<ItemType>& aBag) const = 0;


}; // end BagInterface
#endif
```

NODE.H

```
/** @file Node.h 
    Listing 4-1 */
#ifndef _NODE
#define _NODE

template<class ItemType>
class Node
{
private:
   ItemType        item; // A data item
   Node<ItemType>* next; // Pointer to next node

public:
   Node();
   Node(const ItemType& anItem);
   Node(const ItemType& anItem, Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
   void setItem(const ItemType& anItem);
   void setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
   ItemType getItem() const ;
   Node<ItemType>* getNext() const ;
}; // end Node

#include "Node.cpp"
#endif
```

NODE.CPP

```
#pragma once
/** @file Node.cpp 
    Listing 4-2 */
#include "Node.h"
#include <cstddef>

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node() : next(nullptr)
{
} // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem) : item(anItem), next(nullptr)
{
} // end constructor

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem, Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr) :
                item(anItem), next(nextNodePtr)
{
} // end constructor

template<class ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::setItem(const ItemType& anItem)
{
   item = anItem;
} // end setItem

template<class ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr)
{
   next = nextNodePtr;
} // end setNext

template<class ItemType>
ItemType Node<ItemType>::getItem() const
{
   return item;
} // end getItem

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>* Node<ItemType>::getNext() const
{
   return next;
} // end getNext
```

LINKEDBAG.H

```
/** ADT bag: Link-based implementation.
    @file LinkedBag.h 
    Listing 4-3 */
#ifndef _LINKED_BAG
#define _LINKED_BAG

#include "BagInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

template<class ItemType>
class LinkedBag : public BagInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
   Node<ItemType>* headPtr; // Pointer to first node
   int itemCount;           // Current count of bag items

   // Returns either a pointer to the node containing a given entry
   // or the null pointer if the entry is not in the bag.
   Node<ItemType>* getPointerTo(const ItemType& target) const;

public:
   LinkedBag();
   LinkedBag(const LinkedBag<ItemType>& aBag); // Copy constructor
   virtual ~LinkedBag();                       // Destructor should be virtual
   int getCurrentSize() const;
   bool isEmpty() const;
   bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
   bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
   void clear();
   bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
   int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
   vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
   BagInterface<ItemType>* combine(BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const;
   BagInterface<ItemType>* diff(BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const;
   BagInterface<ItemType>* intersection(BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const;
   BagInterface<ItemType>& operator+(const BagInterface<ItemType>& aBag) const;

}; // end LinkedBag

#include "LinkedBag.cpp"
#endif
```

LINKEDBAG.CPP

```
#pragma once
/** ADT bag: Link-based implementation.
    @file LinkedBag.cpp */

#include "LinkedBag.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstddef>

template <class ItemType>
LinkedBag<ItemType>::LinkedBag()
    : headPtr(nullptr)
    , itemCount(0)
{
} // end default constructor

template <class ItemType> LinkedBag<ItemType>::LinkedBag(const LinkedBag<ItemType>& aBag)
{
    itemCount = aBag.itemCount;
    Node<ItemType>* origChainPtr = aBag.headPtr; // Points to nodes in original chain

    if(origChainPtr == nullptr)
    headPtr = nullptr; // Original bag is empty
    else {
    // Copy first node
    headPtr = new Node<ItemType>();
    headPtr->setItem(origChainPtr->getItem());

    // Copy remaining nodes
    Node<ItemType>* newChainPtr = headPtr;  // Points to last node in new chain
    origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext(); // Advance original-chain pointer

    while(origChainPtr != nullptr) {
        // Get next item from original chain
        ItemType nextItem = origChainPtr->getItem();

        // Create a new node containing the next item
        Node<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>(nextItem);

        // Link new node to end of new chain
        newChainPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);

        // Advance pointer to new last node
        newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();

        // Advance original-chain pointer
        origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
    } // end while

    newChainPtr->setNext(nullptr); // Flag end of chain
    }                                  // end if
} // end copy constructor

template <class ItemType> LinkedBag<ItemType>::~LinkedBag()
{
    clear();
} // end destructor

template <class ItemType> bool LinkedBag<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return itemCount == 0;
} // end isEmpty

template <class ItemType> int LinkedBag<ItemType>::getCurrentSize() const
{
    return itemCount;
} // end getCurrentSize

template <class ItemType> bool LinkedBag<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    // Add to beginning of chain: new node references rest of chain;
    // (headPtr is null if chain is empty)
    Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>();
    nextNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
    nextNodePtr->setNext(headPtr); // New node points to chain
    //   Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>(newEntry, headPtr); // alternate code

    headPtr = nextNodePtr; // New node is now first node
    itemCount++;

    return true;
} // end add

template <class ItemType> vector<ItemType> LinkedBag<ItemType>::toVector() const
{
    vector<ItemType> bagContents;
    Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
    int counter = 0;
    while((curPtr != nullptr) && (counter < itemCount)) {
    bagContents.push_back(curPtr->getItem());
    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    counter++;
    } // end while

    return bagContents;
} // end toVector

template <class ItemType> bool LinkedBag<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anEntry)
{
    Node<ItemType>* entryNodePtr = getPointerTo(anEntry);
    bool canRemoveItem = !isEmpty() && (entryNodePtr != nullptr);
    if(canRemoveItem) {
    // Copy data from first node to located node
    entryNodePtr->setItem(headPtr->getItem());

    // Delete first node
    Node<ItemType>* nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
    headPtr = headPtr->getNext();

    // Return node to the system
    nodeToDeletePtr->setNext(nullptr);
    delete nodeToDeletePtr;
    nodeToDeletePtr = nullptr;

    itemCount--;
    } // end if

    return canRemoveItem;
} // end remove

template <class ItemType> void LinkedBag<ItemType>::clear()
{
    Node<ItemType>* nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
    while(headPtr != nullptr) {
    headPtr = headPtr->getNext();

    // Return node to the system
    nodeToDeletePtr->setNext(nullptr);
    delete nodeToDeletePtr;

    nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
    } // end while
      // headPtr is nullptr; nodeToDeletePtr is nullptr

    itemCount = 0;
} // end clear

template <class ItemType> int LinkedBag<ItemType>::getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    int frequency = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
    while((curPtr != nullptr) && (counter < itemCount)) {
    if(anEntry == curPtr->getItem()) {
        frequency++;
    } // end if

    counter++;
    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    } // end while

    return frequency;
} // end getFrequencyOf

template <class ItemType> bool LinkedBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    return (getPointerTo(anEntry) != nullptr);
} // end contains

/* ALTERNATE 1
template<class ItemType>
bool LinkedBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
   return getFrequencyOf(anEntry) > 0;
}
*/
/* ALTERNATE 2
template<class ItemType>
bool LinkedBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
   bool found = false;
   Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
   int i = 0;
   while (!found && (curPtr != nullptr) && (i < itemCount))
   {
      if (anEntry == curPtr-<getItem())
      {
         found = true;
      }
      else
      {
         i++;
         curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
      }  // end if
   }  // end while

   return found;
}  // end contains
*/

// private
// Returns either a pointer to the node containing a given entry
// or the null pointer if the entry is not in the bag.
template <class ItemType> 
Node<ItemType>* LinkedBag<ItemType>::getPointerTo(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    bool found = false;
    Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;

    while(!found && (curPtr != nullptr)) {
    if(anEntry == curPtr->getItem())
        found = true;
    else
        curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    } // end while

    return curPtr;
} // end getPointerTo

template <class ItemType> 
BagInterface<ItemType>* LinkedBag<ItemType>::combine(BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const
{
    vector<ItemType> items1 = aBag->toVector();
    vector<ItemType> items2 = this->toVector();

    BagInterface<ItemType>* newBag = new LinkedBag<ItemType>();

    if(!aBag->isEmpty()) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < items1.size(); i++) {
        newBag->add(items1[i]);
    }
    }

    if(!this->isEmpty()) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < items2.size(); i++) {
        newBag->add(items2[i]);
    }
    }

    return newBag;
}

template <class ItemType> BagInterface<ItemType>* LinkedBag<ItemType>::diff(BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const
{
    vector<ItemType> items1 = this->toVector();
    vector<ItemType> items2 = aBag->toVector();

    BagInterface<ItemType>* newBag = new LinkedBag<ItemType>();

    if(!aBag->isEmpty() && !this->isEmpty()) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < items1.size(); i++) {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < items2.size(); j++) {
        if(items1[i] == items2[j]) {
            items1.erase(items1.begin() + i);
            items2.erase(items2.begin() + j);
            i = 0;
            j = -1;
        }
        }
    }
    }
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < items1.size(); i++) {
    newBag->add(items1[i]);
    }
    return newBag;
}

template <class ItemType> BagInterface<ItemType>* LinkedBag<ItemType>::intersection(BagInterface<ItemType>* aBag) const
{
    vector<ItemType> items1 = this->toVector();
    vector<ItemType> items2 = aBag->toVector();

    BagInterface<ItemType>* newBag = new LinkedBag<ItemType>();

    if(!aBag->isEmpty() && !this->isEmpty()) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < items1.size(); i++) {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < items2.size(); j++) {
        if(items1[i] == items2[j]) {
            newBag->add(items1[i]);
            items1.erase(items1.begin() + i);
            items2.erase(items2.begin() + j);
            i = 0;
            j = -1;
        }
        }
    }
    }
    return newBag;
}


template <class ItemType>
BagInterface<ItemType>& LinkedBag<ItemType>::operator+(const BagInterface<ItemType>& aBag) const
{
    //BagInterface<ItemType>* newBag = new LinkedBag();
    //return *newBag;

    BagInterface<ItemType> temp = new LinkedBag(aBag);

        Node<ItemType> *n = headPtr;
        while (n)
        {
            temp.Add(n->data);
            n = n->next;
        }

        n = aBag.headPtr;
        while (n)
        {
            temp.Add(n->data);
            n = n->next;
        }
        return temp;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it for a non-templated class?

Comment: Hi Neil,
I do know how for non-templated but I think I am getting confused with (*bagPtr3) = (*bagPtr1) + (*bagPtr2);
being dereferenced and how to use those derefenced values in the implementation. BagPtr3 should return a combination of BagPtr1 and BagPtr2

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what's the problem in your code, as it's not clear what the expected output from running it. Does your code produce unexpected output?

From quick observation looks like you did not declare your `operator+` properly. Most likely instead of returning reference it should return new value. Perhaps you should also have a method that does similar action that `opeartor+` does and make your `operator+` simply call that method:

```
template <class ItemType>
BagInterface<ItemType> LinkedBag<ItemType>::operator+(const BagInterface<ItemType>& aBag) const
{
    return doAdd(aBag); // method that does the same as `operator+`
}
```

In your code your `operator+` return `BagInterface<ItemType>&` instead of `BagInterface<ItemType>`.

Comment: Hey Pavel, I'm sorry you are correct, I made no indication what it should return.
I should be able to do (*bagPtr3) = (*bagPtr1) + (*bagPtr2); and bagPtr3 should be the combined bag of 1 and 2. Like using the combine method I have. I wanted to be able to reuse the combine method but since it works with pointers it doesn't look like I can. I will try what you have provided. Thanks Pavel.

Comment: @TragicWhale Yes, that's exactly how it should work, and to work like that it has to return by value as I corrected. Returning by reference there is just wrong.

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a shot later today. **fingers crossed**